# Does rails have a previous_path/url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

If not, is there a gem I can install that lets me do something like:

```
<%=h link_to "Back", previous_path %>
```

???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you use the built in :back facility?

```
link_to "Back", :back
```

This will link to the referring page, or to the browser's 'back' action. See the  [docs](http://www.51773.com/tools/api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597).

Comment: Didn't know that was there. Handy.

Answer (score -1):

:back works remarkably well for cancels and back buttons.

For redirecting them after a submission I needed to set a session variable.

I do something like this for my feedback form (which can be accessed from any page):

#### In my feedback controller

```
def new
  session[:referrer] = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]
end

def create
  # blah blah, create actions
  redirect_to session[:referrer]
end
```

Can you do that with back?

/ JP

Comment: Okay, for 'back' buttons :back works great. Is there a way to use :back for redirect_to ? Let's say after a feedback has been created I want to return them to their previous page.